# unable to install twitter gem mac osx maverick

Tags: ruby, macos, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to install the gem twitter on mac osx maverick.But getting errors related to make and native extensions.

```
OS: Maverick
MAC OSX 10.9.1

Error: 

ERROR:  Error installing twitter:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make  clean

make
compiling ruby_http_parser.c
```

Read on some questions and blog posts to update brew. But no luck.

```
brew update
Updated Homebrew from 78b4d7d7 to 78b4d7d7.
==> New Formulae
homebrew/dupes/ed
==> Updated Formulae
homebrew/dupes/ab         homebrew/dupes/expect     homebrew/dupes/groff      homebrew/dupes/make       homebrew/dupes/tcpdump
homebrew/dupes/apple-gcc42    homebrew/dupes/fetchmail      homebrew/dupes/httpd      homebrew/dupes/ncurses    homebrew/dupes/tidy
homebrew/dupes/apr        homebrew/dupes/file-formula   homebrew/dupes/lapack     homebrew/dupes/openssh    homebrew/dupes/unzip
homebrew/dupes/apr-util       homebrew/dupes/gdb        homebrew/dupes/less       homebrew/dupes/rsync      homebrew/dupes/whois
homebrew/dupes/diffstat       homebrew/dupes/grep       homebrew/dupes/libpcap    homebrew/dupes/tcl-tk     homebrew/dupes/zlib
==> Deleted Formulae
homebrew/dupes/ant        homebrew/dupes/libarchive     homebrew/dupes/perl
sh-3.2# ls
Aliases     Contributions   ENV     Formula     Homebrew    LinkedKegs  Taps        brew.rb
```

**Any suggestions on fixing this?**

**UPDATE: Adding the complete log of the error when trying to install twitter gem**

```
    sh-3.2# gem install twitter
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:73: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
ERROR:  Error installing twitter:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make  clean

make
compiling ruby_http_parser.c
In file included from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ruby_http_parser.c:1:
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:48:21: error: string.h: No such file or directory
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:58:21: error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:61:23: error: inttypes.h: No such file or directory
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:65:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:67,
                 from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ruby_http_parser.c:1:
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/defines.h:29:21: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ruby_http_parser.c:1:
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:74:20: error: alloca.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:178,
                 from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ruby_http_parser.c:1:
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.homebrew/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/include/limits.h:10:25: error: limits.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:1381,
                 from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ruby_http_parser.c:1:
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/missing.h:28:24: error: sys/time.h: No such file or directory
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/missing.h:37:25: error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:1381,
                 from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ruby_http_parser.c:1:
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/missing.h:56: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘__syscall’
In file included from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:34,
                 from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:1382,
                 from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ruby_http_parser.c:1:
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/st.h:129: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘uint32_t’
In file included from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:1382,
                 from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ruby_http_parser.c:1:
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:286: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rb_fdset_t’
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:380: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘fd_set’
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:380: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘fd_set’
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:380: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘fd_set’
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:380: warning: ‘struct timeval’ declared inside parameter list
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:380: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:381: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘rb_fdset_t’
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:381: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘rb_fdset_t’
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:381: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘rb_fdset_t’
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:381: warning: ‘struct timeval’ declared inside parameter list
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:382: warning: ‘struct timeval’ declared inside parameter list
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:554: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘pid_t’
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:572: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rb_fork’
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:573: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rb_fork_err’
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:575: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rb_waitpid’
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:576: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘pid’
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:577: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rb_spawn’
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:578: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rb_spawn_err’
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:580: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘pid’
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:699: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘uint32_t’
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:824: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘long’
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:825: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘long’
In file included from ruby_http_parser.c:3:
ryah_http_parser.h:209: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘uint32_t’
ryah_http_parser.h:265: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘uint16_t’
ruby_http_parser.c: In function ‘ParserWrapper_init’:
ruby_http_parser.c:44: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘status_code’
ruby_http_parser.c:45: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘http_major’
ruby_http_parser.c:46: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘http_minor’
ruby_http_parser.c: In function ‘ParserWrapper_free’:
ruby_http_parser.c:77: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘free’
ruby_http_parser.c: In function ‘on_message_begin’:
ruby_http_parser.c:102: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘data’
ruby_http_parser.c:104: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strlen’
ruby_http_parser.c:104: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
ruby_http_parser.c:106: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
ruby_http_parser.c:108: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
ruby_http_parser.c: In function ‘on_url’:
ruby_http_parser.c:125: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘data’
ruby_http_parser.c: In function ‘on_header_field’:
ruby_http_parser.c:131: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘data’
ruby_http_parser.c: In function ‘on_header_value’:
ruby_http_parser.c:144: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘data’
ruby_http_parser.c:146: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
ruby_http_parser.c:160: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
ruby_http_parser.c:162: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
ruby_http_parser.c:167: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
ruby_http_parser.c:169: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
ruby_http_parser.c:172: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
ruby_http_parser.c: In function ‘on_headers_complete’:
ruby_http_parser.c:190: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘data’
ruby_http_parser.c:192: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
ruby_http_parser.c: In function ‘on_body’:
ruby_http_parser.c:211: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘data’
ruby_http_parser.c:213: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
ruby_http_parser.c: In function ‘on_message_complete’:
ruby_http_parser.c:230: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘data’
ruby_http_parser.c:232: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
ruby_http_parser.c: In function ‘Parser_alloc_by_type’:
ruby_http_parser.c:262: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘data’
ruby_http_parser.c: In function ‘Parser_execute’:
ruby_http_parser.c:314: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
ruby_http_parser.c:320: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
ruby_http_parser.c:322: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘upgrade’
ruby_http_parser.c: In function ‘Parser_upgrade_p’:
ruby_http_parser.c:381: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘upgrade’
ruby_http_parser.c: In function ‘Parser_http_version’:
ruby_http_parser.c:388: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘http_major’
ruby_http_parser.c:388: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘http_minor’
ruby_http_parser.c:391: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘http_major’
ruby_http_parser.c:391: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘http_minor’
ruby_http_parser.c: In function ‘Parser_http_major’:
ruby_http_parser.c:398: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘http_major’
ruby_http_parser.c:398: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘http_minor’
ruby_http_parser.c:401: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘http_major’
ruby_http_parser.c: In function ‘Parser_http_minor’:
ruby_http_parser.c:408: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘http_major’
ruby_http_parser.c:408: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘http_minor’
ruby_http_parser.c:411: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘http_minor’
ruby_http_parser.c: In function ‘Parser_http_method’:
ruby_http_parser.c:419: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘method’
ruby_http_parser.c:419: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘method’
ruby_http_parser.c:419: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
ruby_http_parser.c:419: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘method’
ruby_http_parser.c:419: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘method’
ruby_http_parser.c: In function ‘Parser_status_code’:
ruby_http_parser.c:428: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘status_code’
ruby_http_parser.c:429: error: ‘ryah_http_parser’ has no member named ‘status_code’
ruby_http_parser.c: In function ‘Parser_set_header_value_type’:
ruby_http_parser.c:451: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
ruby_http_parser.c: In function ‘Init_ruby_http_parser’:
ruby_http_parser.c:473: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
ruby_http_parser.c:474: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
ruby_http_parser.c:475: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
ruby_http_parser.c:476: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
ruby_http_parser.c:477: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
ruby_http_parser.c:478: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
ruby_http_parser.c:479: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
ruby_http_parser.c:481: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
ruby_http_parser.c:482: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
ruby_http_parser.c:483: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
make: *** [ruby_http_parser.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/1.9.1/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/gem_make.out
sh-3.2# sh-3.2# gem install twitter
sh: sh-3.2#: command not found
sh-3.2# Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
sh: Building: command not found
sh-3.2# /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:73: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
sh: /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:73:: No such file or directory
sh-3.2# ERROR:  Error installing twitter:
sh: ERROR:: command not found
sh-3.2# ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
sh: ERROR:: command not found
sh-3.2# 
sh-3.2#     /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- extconf.rb (LoadError)
sh-3.2# creating Makefile

make  clean

make
compiling ruby_http_parser.c
In file included from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ruby_http_parser.c:1:
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:48:21: error: string.h: No such file or directory
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:58:21: error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:61:23: error: inttypes.h: No such file or directory
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:65:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:67,
                 from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ruby_http_parser.c:1:
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubsh: creating: command not found
sh-3.2# 
sh-3.2# make  clean
make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
sh-3.2# 
sh-3.2# make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
sh-3.2# compiling ruby_http_parser.c
sh: compiling: command not found
sh-3.2# In file included from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
sh: In: command not found
sh-3.2#                  from ruby_http_parser.c:1:
from: can't read /var/mail/ruby_http_parser.c:1:
sh-3.2# /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:48:21: error: string.h: No such file or directory
sh: /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:48:21:: No such file or directory
sh-3.2# /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:58:21: error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
sh: /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:58:21:: No such file or directory
sh-3.2# /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:61:23: error: inttypes.h: No such file or directory
sh: /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:61:23:: No such file or directory
sh-3.2# /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:65:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
sh: /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:65:19:: No such file or directory
sh-3.2# In file included from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:67,
                 from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ruby_http_parser.c:1:
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/defines.h:29:21: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ruby_http_parser.c:1:
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:74:20: error: alloca.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:178,
                 from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ruby_http_parser.c:1:
/Users/sandeepuppuluri/.homebrew/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/include/limits.h:10:25: error: limits.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Ush: In: command not found
sh-3.2#                  from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
from: can't read /var/mail//Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
sh-3.2#                  from ruby_http_parser.c:1:
from: can't read /var/mail/ruby_http_parser.c:1:
sh-3.2# /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/defines.h:29:21: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
sh: /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/defines.h:29:21:: No such file or directory
sh-3.2# In file included from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
sh: In: command not found
sh-3.2#                  from ruby_http_parser.c:1:
from: can't read /var/mail/ruby_http_parser.c:1:
sh-3.2# /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:74:20: error: alloca.h: No such file or directory
sh: /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:74:20:: No such file or directory
sh-3.2# In file included from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:178,
sh: In: command not found
sh-3.2#                  from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
from: can't read /var/mail//Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
sh-3.2#                  from ruby_http_parser.c:1:
from: can't read /var/mail/ruby_http_parser.c:1:
sh-3.2# /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.homebrew/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/include/limits.h:10:25: error: limits.h: No such file or directory
sh: /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.homebrew/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/include/limits.h:10:25:: No such file or directory
sh-3.2# In file included from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:1381,
sh: In: command not found
sh-3.2#                  from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
from: can't read /var/mail//Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
sh-3.2#                  from ruby_http_parser.c:1:
from: can't read /var/mail/ruby_http_parser.c:1:
sh-3.2# /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/missing.h:28:24: error: sys/time.h: No such file or directory
sh: /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/missing.h:28:24:: No such file or directory
sh-3.2# /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/missing.h:37:25: error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
sh: /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/missing.h:37:25:: No such file or directory
sh-3.2# In file included from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:1381,
sh: In: command not found
sh-3.2#                  from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
from: can't read /var/mail//Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
sh-3.2#                  from ruby_http_parser.c:1:
from: can't read /var/mail/ruby_http_parser.c:1:
sh-3.2# /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/missing.h:56: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘__syscall’
sh: /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/missing.h:56:: No such file or directory
sh: ’,: command not found
sh-3.2# In file included from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:34,
sh: In: command not found
sh-3.2#                  from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:1382,
from: can't read /var/mail//Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:1382,
sh-3.2#                  from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
from: can't read /var/mail//Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
sh-3.2#                  from ruby_http_parser.c:1:
from: can't read /var/mail/ruby_http_parser.c:1:
sh-3.2# /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/st.h:129: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘uint32_t’
sh: /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/st.h:129:: No such file or directory
sh-3.2# In file included from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:1382,
sh: In: command not found
sh-3.2#                  from /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
from: can't read /var/mail//Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
sh-3.2#                  from ruby_http_parser.c:1:
from: can't read /var/mail/ruby_http_parser.c:1:
sh-3.2# /Users/sandeepuppuluri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.
```

Comment: Can you please share the complete error message? Thanks.

Comment: Hi andHapp,Thanks for your response. I added the complete error message that appeared in the log.

Comment: It seems your system development headers are absent. For [tag:osx] you are able to install with [tag:brew].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all who provided the inputs.

I was able to install the twitter gem successfully after uninstalling homebrew and reinstalling it again.

For some reason my development headers are screwed up when I upgraded to mac osx maverick